# shell, вывести первую строку файла И еще одну строку по grep

Tags: парсер, sh

Пререквизиты:

1. Это обязательно должен быть однострочник. Чем короче, тем лучше.
2. Только POSIX совместимые команды и их ключи. Никакого perl, python и тд.
3. Результат надо склеить в одну строку.

Что-то уже час сижу туплю, не знаю с какой стороны подойти к задаче.

Финальная задача проста - пробежать по чертовой куче Linux серверов (SLES, RHEL) и вытащить из них информацию о вендоре (suse, red hat), мажорной версии и патчлевеле. И всю эту радость надо реализовать однострочником (не спрашивайте почему).

Самый простой вариант видится так:

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null | head -n1
```

С RHEL все отлично, а для SLES кроме первой строки надо из `/etc/SuSE-release` вытащить строку начинающуюся на `PATCHLEVEL`

Тобишь надо, чтобы для `/etc/redhat-release` выдавалась только первая строка, а для `/etc/SuSE-release` первая строка и строка с `PATCHLEVEL`, причем склееные в одну строку.

**Собственно вопрос - как?**

```
server:path$ cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 0
# This file is deprecated and will be removed in a future service pack or release.
# Please check /etc/os-release for details about this release.
```

**UPD**
Для SLES первая строка файла имеет такой вид

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
```

Для RHEL такой

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null | sed -n '1{/SUSE/{h;be};p};/PATCHLEVEL/{H;x;s/\n/ /;p};:e'
```

Расшифровка:

```
1               Если первая строка то ...
/SUSE/          Если это SUSE
{
  h             Сохранить первую строку в дополнительном буфере
  be            Переход к метке "e" (конец обработки)
}
p               Напечатать содержимое первой строки (SUSE не было)
/PATCHLEVEL/    Когда встречен PACHLEVEL выполнить следующее:
H               Добавить к дополнительному буферу перевод каретки и текущую строку
x               Обменять содержимое основного и дополнительного буферов
s/\n/ /         Заменить перевод каретки на пробел (в основном буфере)
p               распечатать основной буфер
:e              метка для прерывания обработки
```

Comment: Собственно один файл обработать проблем нет, засада будет, когда этому sed'у дописать еще один входящий файл, в котором  строки с `PATCHLEVEL` нет. Я не знаю заранее, какой именно это Linux, RHEL или SLES

Comment: @rjhdby У SUSE всегда в первой строке `SUSE` ?

Comment: @rjhdby Поправил включив реакцию на текст первой строки

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь главное случайно дьявола этой строкой не вызвать :)

Answer (score 3):

Может так?

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release 2>/dev/null  | head -n1 | tr '\n' ' '; grep PATCHLEVEL /etc/SuSE-release 2>/dev/null; cat /etc/redhat-release 2>/dev/null | head -n1
```

Comment: можно еще проще `(head -qn1 /etc/SuSE-release /etc/redhat-release|tr -d'\n';cat /etc/SuSE-release|grep PATCH) 2>/dev/null`, но это уже не однострочник. За попытку плюсик.